# Any ideas on how to write a comments schema in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database-design

I've two collections Users and posts. I'm building something similar to Facebook. How can I design schema for comments so that I can have comments for comments (Should be able to reply to comment at any depth)

Comment: create a comment model with reference to reply comment as array and each comment should be insert in comments collection

Answer (score 0):

Here I have my query to find comment per user/logged in user - just pass in ID:

```
db.comments.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "_uid": 1
    }
  ]
})
```

My data is like:

```
db={
  "comments": [
    {
      "_uid": 1,
      "city": "New York",
      "comments": "top comment"
    },
    {
      "_uid": 2,
      "city": "Seattle",
      "comments": "middle earth is where the beasts love"
    },
    {
      "_uid": 3,
      "city": "Seattle",
      "comments": "i love comment systems"
    }
  ]
}
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "_uid": 1,
    "city": "New York",
    "comments": "top comment"
  }
]
```

If I wanted to find ALL comments:

```
db.comments.find({})
```

If I wanted to find ALL comments per POST- then maybe modify the data a bit and add a POST URL to object:

```
db={
      "comments": [
        {
          "_uid": 1,
          "city": "New York",
          "comments": "top comment",
          "postUrl": "/posts/postID=12345"
        },
        {
          "_uid": 1,
          "city": "New York",
          "comments": "top comment",
          "postUrl": "/posts/postID=12345"
        },....
      ]
    }
```

Now we can query ALL comments from the POST '12345':

```
db.comments.find({
  "postUrl": "/posts/postID=12345"
})
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "_uid": 1,
    "city": "New York",
    "comments": "top comment",
    "postUrl": "/posts/postID=12345"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "_uid": 2,
    "city": "Seattle",
    "comments": "middle earth is where the beasts love",
    "postUrl": "/posts/postID=12345"
  }
]
```